# Java Server- accepting more clients

Tags: java, sockets

Code below is server accepting only one client.Could someone explain me, how to make server accepting for example two clients? Thanks very much for help.

```
public class test{
private static ServerSocket server;
private static Socket client;
private static BufferedReader reader;
private static String text;

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    server=new ServerSocket(63400);
    System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
    client=server.accept();

    reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

    while((text=reader.readLine())!=null)
        System.out.println(text);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `accept()` returns, pass the `Socket` to a new `Thread` created to handle that client; then loop back and call `accept()` again.

If this sounds too complicated, then you're trying to run  before you can walk. You'll need to learn about [loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), and about [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), and then you'll be able to tackle it.

Answer (score 1):

Handle your Clients threaded.
The Code below is simplified!

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {
  Socket client;
  InputStream inputstream;

  public ClientHandler(Socket client) {
    this.client= client;
    inputstream = client.getInputStream();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
    String text;

    while((text=reader.readLine())!=null)
      System.out.println(text);
  }
}
```